What is the role of, "of the outcome?" in this sentence?
I am trying to diagram the question, "What can be known of the outcome?"
I cannot argue the role of "of the outcome?"
I know it is a prepositional phrase modifying 'can be known' but I can't explain why.
What's happening here?

It means the same thing as "about the outcome". Does that make it easier?

It's structurally the same as What is useful about diagramming questions? Does that help?

What system of sentence diagramming are you using?

of preposition "5 a : relating to : about". I'm not sure what your difficulty is with considering it as a prepositional phrase: do you think "of" always connects two nouns, or is it the complex "can be known" that's giving the problem and you don't know whether it relates to the entirety of that or just "be known" or some other part?

The PP "of the outcome" is licensed by the verb "known", and thus is a complement of the verb.

Thank you @BillJ this is what I was wondering about. I didn't have a name for this category of phrase. Thank you.


What can be known of the outcome?

The preposition phrase "of the outcome" is licensed by the verb "known" and thus is a complement.
Licensing: a syntactic element that is either required or specifically permitted by a verb or other lexical unit.

thank you. This is what I was wondering about.
